Clipping hosted features using ArcGIS Pro
I added two input layers. I did Add Data, then in the file folder I went to the Portal. From there I added one layer from "My Groups", and another layer from "ArcGIS Online".
I want to clip one of these layers using the other. I opened the "Clip Layer" tool, and my Input Layer and Clip Layer both got this error:

Error 160938  This operation is not supported against >input datasets from a feature service.

How can I make these usable for the Clip Layer operation or is there a way to make a local copy of these layers?
I don't want to edit the hosted layers, I just want to make a clip I can use on my own map.

Do you have permissions to download/copy the data from those layers from AGOL?  If you don't have the required permissions to do this, then some other tools will not work with them (ie, you cannot make derivative products from them).  If you do have permissions to download/copy the layers, then just make a copy in ArcGIS Pro, and clip that copied layer.

I was able to create local copies by exporting. For some reason, each layer required this to be done in a different way.
For one layer, in the Contents Pane, with "Drawing Order", I right clicked on the layer and did
Data > Export Features
For the other layer, I found a place to download it independently of Esri hosting.
